# product filter with if or

Tags: jquery, filter

I am trying to get a product filter working which is almost there.  I want to the user to be able to select shirt, which then shows all shirts then blue which shows all blue shirts and then in they check pink it shows all blue and pink shirts.  At the moment I can only get it to show if all conditions are true but I want it to show if any of that dataset is true

My fiddle is here

http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/2keVN/2/

```
$('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
{
var $lis = $('.results > li'),
    $checked = $('input:checked');

if ($checked.length)
{
    var selector = $checked.map(function ()
    {
        return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
    }).get().join('');

    $lis.hide().filter(selector).show().addClass("show");     
}
else
{
    $lis.show().removeClass("show");
}
});
```

Comment: While I can understand showing, for example, the pink and blue shirts (using checkboxes to *broaden* the search criteria), I honestly can't imagine a situation in which, while looking for a new shirt I'd want to broaden my search to inclucde skirts, or trousers. To my mind, you should use `radio`s to narrow down the clothing-type, and checkboxes to broaden the colour-types. But that's maybe just a very personal UI preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**EDIT:** I've modified the method to be able to filter exclusively. This way, you'll be able to filter by, say, shirts and trousers that are green or pink.

```
$(function(){
    $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function()
    {
        var $lis = $('.results > li'),
            $types = $('.filter-grp-type input:checked'),
            $colors = $('.filter-grp-color input:checked');

        if ($types.length)
        {
            var selector = $types.map(function ()
            {
                return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
            }).get().join(', ');

            $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();     
        }
        else
        {
            $lis.show();
        }

        $lis = $lis.filter(":visible");

        if ($colors.length)
        {
            var selector = $colors.map(function ()
            {
                return '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
            }).get().join(', ');

            $lis.hide().filter(selector).show();     
        }
    });
})
```

When you were building up your "selector" string, you were just concatenating it. jQuery will then only filter those items which have ALL the classes in your selector.

I agree with David Thomas. Rather make the selection of clothing type a mutually exclusive one, i.e. radio buttons.

Comment: thanks I thought about the .join(', ') method originally but this then displays a list that has only one filter attached to it, so if I choose pink and shirts I get all items that are pink and all shirts of any colour which is not really a filter then

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect:)  I have accepted this answer

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest first changing your HTML, to reflect that you only want to select one category of clothing (so use `<input type="radio" />`):

```
  <div class="tags">
   <fieldset class="filter-grp">
    <label><input type="radio" rel="skirt" name="year" /> skirt </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" rel="trousers" name="year" /> trousers </label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" rel="shirt" name="year" /> shirt </label><br>
    </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset class="filter-grp">
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="blue" name="type"  /> blue</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="pink" name="type"  /> pink</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" rel="green" name="type"  /> green</label><br>
   </fieldset>
   <br>
</div>

<ul class="results">
   <li class="blue skirt"> blue skirt</li>
   <li class="pink shirt">pink shirt</li>
   <li class="pink skirt">pink skirt</li>
   <li class="blue shirt">blue shirt</li>
   <li class="blue trousers">blue trousers</li>
   <li class="green skirt">green skirt</li>
   <li class="blue shirt">blue shirt</li>
   <li class="pink trousers">pink trousers</li>
   <li class="blue trousers">blue trousers</li>
   <li class="blue skirt">blue skirt</li>
   <li class="green shirt">green shirt</li>
</ul>    ​
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.tags').delegate('input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio]', 'change', function() {
        var $lis = $('.results > li'),
            $category = $('input:radio:checked')
            .attr('rel'),
            $colors = $('input:checkbox:checked'),
            selectors = $colors.map(
                function(){
                    return '.' + $category + '.' + $(this).attr('rel');
                }).get().join(', ');
        if ($category.length && $colors.length) {
                        $lis
                            .hide()
                            .filter(selectors)
                            .show()
                            .addClass("show");
        }
        else {
            $lis.show().removeClass("show");
        }
    });
})​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2keVN/6/).

Comment: thanks, the problem with using the radio buttons is that you are forcing the user to make 2 selections as it doesn't filter by the radio button until you select a check box.